# Scrapy how to set DEPTH_LIMIT from a command line argument

Tags: python, scrapy

I currently have DEPTH_LIMIT set in the settings module for the scraper I am building.  I would like to be able to pass a depth limit in as a command line argument.  I have tried the following as a constructor for the crawler (and variations of it):

```
    def __init__(self, max_depth=3, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.settings['DEPTH_LIMIT'] = int(max_depth)
```

but, I get an error and the stack dump ends with:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spider.py", line 41, in crawler
      assert hasattr(self, '_crawler'), "Spider not bounded to any crawler"
   AssertionError: Spider not bounded to any crawler
```

Even trying to print self.settings['DEPTH_LIMIT'] in the constructor causes and error.  How can I set the DEPTH_LIMIT in a crawler from a command line argument?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem does not reside in the two lines of code you posted but elsewhere. Please paste the complete MySpider class.

Answer (score 2):

you may try this approach:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.settings['DEPTH_LIMIT'] = int(kwargs.pop('max_depth', 3))
    super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

for details on `pop` you may refer to [python official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.pop#dict.pop)

if this does not works, please add some more code on how you created the crawler object (e.g. the class definition, and where do you define `settings` attribute)

Comment: as is, the same error is occurring when I try to set self.settings['DEPTH_LIMIT'], I am looking into defining the settings now ...

Comment: The scrapy docs indicate that pre-defined settings such as DEPTH_LIMIT can be set from the command line (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=depth#global-overrides).  Whether this works in Scrapyd or not I will find out when I get there.  Thanks furins for taking the time to help me out